# Generic trim function in java?

Tags: java

i have a requirement, where i need to develop a single method which accepts any type of paramter(String or Integer etc) and applies trim() to remove leading and trialing spaces. please help me how to write generic method to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely if an integer has trailing spaces, it's a string anyway...?

Comment: How do you remove trailing spaces from an integer?

Comment: An integer is a number. It doesn't *have* spaces. Spaces only apply to textual types. What would `trim(Button)` mean for example?

Comment: What do you mean by removing trailing spaces from an Integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make a lot of sense, but here it goes:

```
public String trim(Object o) {
  if (o != null) { 
    return o.toString().trim();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java has strictly defined types, it's not PHP or Javascript. Integer does not have spaces. Simply use [trim()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method of String object. If your 'integer' is actually a string, do `(String.valueOf(x)).trim()`

Comment: +1 - and if he needs to come up with an own method: `String trim(Object x) { return String.valueOf(x).trim(); }` :)

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. if an integer is like 12345---. --- indicates 3 spaces. how can i remove? do i need to convert it to string before trimming?

Comment: As said, 12345--- is not an integer anyway. It's already a string.

Comment: +1: A `String` which contains digits is not an `Integer` Only an `Integer` is an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

> if an integer is like 12345---. --- indicates 3 spaces. how can i remove? do i need to convert it to string before trimming?

If an 'integer' has trailing spaces, it is already the string representation of the integer, not the integer itself.  Therefore:

```
String i = "12345   ";
String trimmed = i.trim();
```

By contrast, the following is simply not legal

```
int i = "12345   ";  // compilation error
```

and a string representation of an integer produced like this:

```
String i = String.valueOf(12345);
```

will not have leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In java, all objects have [.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method which returns string representation of that object.

You can then call [.trim()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method on that string, so your function may look like this:

```
public static String trimAny(Object o) {
    return o.toString().trim();
}
```